# Is it possible to relocate my water heater?

Tags: bathroom, boiler, hot-water, water-tank

I'm planning a complete refit of my bathroom, hopefully converting to a wet room, and I just wanted to get some idea of my options.

The bathroom is (sadly) very small, around 1.7m x 2.3m. This is not helped by the fact the hot water tank with immersion heater takes up one corner of the room. (0.7m square)

I'm also assuming the fact I wouldn't be able to damp proof the cupboard (and hence would have a second perimeter door) would make it more tricky to convert to a wet room.

I'm fairly sure the boiler in the kitchen is not a combi boiler at present.

What are my options, how difficult to achieve, preferable for decent hot water supply?

- Can I move the hot water tank into the loft?
- Can I move the hot water tank into the garage? (Kitchen wall partially shared)
- Can I remove the hot water tank if I go over to combi? (or have I misunderstood what I need to change over to hot water "on demand"?)
- Something else?

I'd love to get the space back into the bathroom, and I really would like to go wet room with walk in if at all possible.

UK based if it makes any difference for the building regs etc.

Comment: Just wanted to add - I know there are questions on here about dealing with these jobs individually. I just am unsure which option I should be looking at to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Regulations, Regulations, Regulations. However, your existing boiler should have been installed under some previous regulations so changing over to a combi and getting rid of the tank stuff shouldn't be a problem for a qualified gas safe engineer. One of the safety aspects is "Ventilation", but you already have a boiler in place so spend a bit of money on getting legal/professional advice and then invite 3 companies to quote you. Good luck